# Visual Studio 2019 vb.net Masked Text Box is reverting the AutoSize property to "true" automatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, maskedtextbox

In VB.net, Visual Studio 2019, I am looking to make a Masked Text Box height taller than the AutoSize allows me to, so I use the code:

```
Me.MaskedTextBox.AutoSize = False
```

I am able to type it in and I do not get any errors and I can change the height without any issues. Even though "AutoSize" does not show in the [auto complete box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5oCQ.png)

If I go back to edit any part of the control though, the autosize lines disappears and the value reverts back to true, reverting the height back to the autosize allowed value.

I was looking in the MaskedTextBox in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=netframework-4.8) and it looks like Autosize it a property that can change even though MaskedTextBox does not like Multi-line.

Is there a way to make the "autosize = false" and height to stay and not revert back?

Comment: The AutoSize property is intentionally hidden, as it is for TextBox.  [Source comments](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,238) explain why.  It computes its height based on the Font, so if you want it taller then you need to select a bigger font.

Comment: In this instance, I am forced by the design aspects to make the height larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your own that pre-sets the property for you:

```
Public Class MaskedTextBoxEx
  Inherits MaskedTextBox

  Public Sub New()
    Me.AutoSize = False
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It works and it is stable but is does not bring the text down with the height increase so it leaves white space under the text. Do you know of a way to do that? The bottom of the text is two pix above the bottom of the box?

Comment: @DerikWasilewski That can't be done really.  The way around that is to make the TextBox AutoSize = True again and make it borderless, place it inside a panel.  Now you can control the position the way you want and the panel acts as your TextBox border.